# Exclude directories using python dirsync module

Tags: python-3.x

I want to sync two different directories using the dirsync module, but exclude some specific folders.
In the documentation (https://pypi.org/project/dirsync/) it says the exclude need to be a regex pattern but I cant quite make it work.
For example, lets say we have these directories
c:\folder1\folder2

c:\folder1\folder3

d:\folder1\

I want to sync c:\folder1\ with d:\folder1\ and exclude folder3, so basically the folder c:\folder1\folder2 will be copied and created in d:\

```
from dirsync import sync

src = r'c:\folder1'
dst = r'd:\folder1'
sync(src, dst, 'diff', exclude='^folder3')
```

this won't work and I can't quite understand why.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "this won't work"?

Comment: @ScottHunter without the exclude, the output contains which files and directories exist only in the source folder (in my example, folder2, folder3), after adding the exclude it will say there is no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

The exclude option expects a list of regexp:
exclude=['^folder3']